# Why do RNGCryptoServiceProvider values always end with equals signs?

Tags: c#, cryptography, passwords, base64, password-protection

Here is my method:

```
public static string GenerateRandomString(int bytes)
{
    var rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
    var randomBytes = new byte[bytes];
    rng.GetBytes(randomBytes);
    return Convert.ToBase64String(randomBytes);
}
```

Every value generated:

i.e.:

```
Qcr6OgNxkGzVebNl00Dtk7yCaz64owUx7pKEhl1Ogn4=
IGFLQB0OrReDB3P6nuZgqZIkTwTtch9Fk3Rx/DL4CgI=
UAJwLwIPYEJ9SzMAK/EMiUJ/DHhmfy6UVMM5MU6Dcpg=
```

always ends with "=" - why is this?

I'm sending this as a random string for a password reset email and am having issues with Microsoft Outlook not picking up the = at the end of the link. Is anyone aware of a way around this without simply chopping off the last character of the string?

Comment: remember - RNGCryptoServiceProvider is not returning a string; it's a series of bytes - the '=' is a facet of base 64 encoding; run it through wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It has to do with the number of bytes returned.  The = is used as padding for base64.

**EDIT**

Using your algorithm I generated strings using between 1 and 20 bytes, printing 1 result per line.  As you can see, some strings end with equal signs, others do not.

```
Ng==
HAo=
g+h1
pdR+cQ==
z5bFWwc=
BilTQWCU
kXo96Jilxw==
7jc16UHgbGc=
DnLzoSDUNVfQ
6MwGWLD3ZcbfZA==
hADhg4HFdMVi1n0=
cWm2HEKs48VaoYgl
TrwxX20FmEs7o8u2ag==
WLORuUzewYDB18XFAcc=
tSnvFVVm/NZ2tkXJnB6V
McUWf0mAmM5/0Upu+eYd+w==
Eln3QPMr2VjXt4e3GsZuOXo=
DBYLTG3fDbMC5I1bnYmG/NxH
KgGhxdZjmjUypsqnbQUMCJzVrQ==
yI+3sFdzBX4Xfb2u6xuzQdS9II0=
```

**EDIT #2**

I realized that I explained why the = occurs, but never suggested another way to generate your URL parameter.  One such way is the [System.Web.HttpServerUtility.UrlTokenEncode()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.urltokenencode.aspx) method which converts an array of bytes to an url-friendly format.  To convert the string back to an array of bytes, use the [System.Web.HttpServerUtility.UrlTokenDecode()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.urltokendecode.aspx) method.

Comment: Funny, I just did the same thing with my own code. Was thinking I probably should have mentioned what I was passing to the method. I was passing _32_ before. Passing _33_ gets rid of the equals sign. Which makes sense to me according to the wikipedia link @Andras Zoltan provided. Thanks!